# javascript how to fix pitfalls counter

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I'm trying to run a for loop and print the current index without use let

here my code:

```
function init() {
  for (var index = 0; index < 5; ++index) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(index);
    }, index);
  }
}
```

I expected to: 0 1 2 3 4
but i get 5 5 5 5 5

Once the Var  replace in Let the problem will be solved

I want to stay with Var

How can the problem be solved?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function init() {
  for (var index = 0; index < 5; ++index) {
   const i = index;
   setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
   }, i);
  }
 }
```

This should work.

Comment: it is posible to stay with timeout and get the index?

Comment: not sure, You could also use setInterval if you want something to run continuosly after a certain amount of delay. maybe that'll work for you.